# simple infinite series question

Tags: discussion, undeletion

The question [Simple infinite series question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124956/simple-infinite-series-question) was answered in the comments, then deleted by OP. I have voted to undelete, on the grounds that the question was no simpler than lots of the questions posted at m.se, and the comments might help someone in the future. Anyone else care to vote to undelete?

Comment: If we undelete, maybe we can censor the potentially offensive exclamation by the OP towards the end of the dialogue :)

Comment: Why not add an answer in the first place? See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments

Comment: @Ary: Maybe my teaching style is not a good fit for a "Q&A" site. Often I prefer a more socratic (less "spoonfed") approach to the learning process. Eventually my comments may turn into an answer, but when I'm the first and only commenter for a few minutes, it seems harmless - until the OP deletes the question, of course!

Comment: Unrelated to the case at hand, another option, which you do not mention, is the reverse move: to delete as many of said (bad) questions as possible, on the ground that each of them *dilutes* in effect the overall value of the site by making it more difficult to find the good ones.

Comment: @TheChaz: You can always start off with an answer and edit it later, while keeping the discussion localized to the comments of the answer rather than the question. Imagine if different people started off in the comments to the question, there would be too much noise. Anyway, this is just a suggestion, but I do want to emphasize that the site does encourage having content in the form of answers, rather than comments (up/downvoting/full text searching/community user bumping questions etc).

Comment: @Ary: I will take that into consideration. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Didier, we'd have to have a community consensus on what makes a question bad, and I'm not sure we have that. Or possibly the questions we'd all agree are bad are already being deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is reopened, and I have [answered it](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124965/7850).

Now there is a whole other discussion going on in the comments!